# what is proxy controller?

Tags: ros, pid, microcontroller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In joint_trajectory_action_controller, there is a [proxy controller mode](http://ros.org/rosdoclite/fuerte/api/control_toolbox/html/classcontrol__toolbox_1_1LimitedProxy.html#a6ae62d76967b9a9117653c3e39f1048e). I am wondering what is proxy controller? What's difference between proxy controller and normal [pid controller](http://ros.org/rosdoclite/groovy/api/control_toolbox/html/classcontrol__toolbox_1_1Pid.html#a59a052f4d6bf02a742ed6046d24374cf)?

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64234/what-is-proxy-controller?/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A proxy controller allows to converge to a reference signal without overshoots, especially when the reference is far from the current state. The [cpp file](https://github.com/willowgarage/ros_control/blob/master/control_toolbox/src/limited_proxy.cpp#L42) has a more detailed description.

I created an [issue](https://github.com/willowgarage/ros_controllers/issues/9) to move the documentation to the header with proper Doxygen tags, so it can be easier to find.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2013-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-06-23**:
Hi Adolfo, I try to read the cpp file, but I found it's hard for me to understand it especially I have no idea about the concept of proxy controller. Could you please give me a link which describing the concept and principle of proxy control? Thx a lot!

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2013-06-24**:
I'm not a user of this feature, and can't say if the implementation maps a reference publication 1:1, or whether the authors introduced custom modifications. You might consider contacting the original authors, or someone familiar with this specific implementation. That's as much as I can help.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-06-24**:
Ok, thank you!

**Comment by [gustavogoretkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/11151/gustavogoretkin/) on 2015-03-16**:
It appears that as of Hydro, `control_toolbox` has moved to https://github.com/ros-controls/control_toolbox. The version for groovy is https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/tree/groovy-devel/control_toolbox